# Positioning of dropdown menu in CSS Problem

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown, navbar

Sorry my work is a mess this is my first college project and I think this is a big mess.
I do not have anyone to refer to and I've spent hours trying to fix my mess. My dropdown content inside the navigation bar will display even if I placed the code "display:none;" also can you explain me what is wrong please. :D

```
The code is below and I've uploaded to
```

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| cell 3 |  |

https://codepen.io/Eman-Rusiana/pen/RwePoLg if it helps?I'm so sorry I am new to this T_T.

I'd be really grateful if someone could help - My brain is fried.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, welcome to  SO! Please take the [tour] and post your code as a running [reprex].

Answer (score 0):

You need to `position: relative` on parent `li` and also need `position: absolute` and `top: 50px` on  child `.dropdown` class.

Like this:

```
.topnav ul li {position: relative;}
.topnav ul li .dropdown {position: absolute; display: inline-block; top: 50px;}
```

Comment: That is very helpful of you. I appreciate how you help me. I wish I could've said thank you sooner.